# Is there a way to substitute a small piece of code (e.g. a statement) with a more friendly alias in Delphi 10.4?

Tags: delphi, alias, delphi-10.4-sydney

I'm working with Delphi 10.4.

At some places of my code I have to write long identifiers on long statements (e.g. `ProductsForSale.fieldByName('quantity').asInteger * ..... / ....` etc.). Is there a way to assign a friendly alias (e.g. `TheCost`) to this piece of code to substitute it everywhere in the application?

I don't want to use a variable or a function to do this. Only text substitution.

Comment: Use a function. We don't have macros in Delphi. We like using functions.

Comment: Are you aware of the code completition feature (Ctrl + Space)?

Comment: @DelphiCoder Code completion is not equivalent to the extract method refactoring

Comment: *Why* do you exclude variables/functions?

Comment: @UliGerhardt. Using a variable is not convenient because when the value of the code changes, I have to reassign it to the variable. The function, on the other hand, requires more time to perform (eg in a long loop it would be important).
A replacement would be very useful because it would only affect the compilation stage.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I know, but the QP was complaining about writing a lot.

Comment: @jim "The function, on the other hand, requires more time to perform". No, this is not true. Short functions can be inlined, which avoids all overhead calling a function.

Comment: @DelphiCoder. My problem is that a statement is too long and so difficult to understand when you debug the code. A short friendly name would make it much easier.

Comment: @Matej. I have never dealt with inline functions but I find it very interesting. It works almost as I would like! I will try it

Comment: A function call is trivial compared to the code that executes (`FieldbyName`). You are falling into the trap of premature optimisation. Inlining won't make any measurable difference here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan. But I can replace ProductsForSale.fieldByName ("quantity"). asInteger with e.g. quantity. And bigger statements shorter

Comment: I don't understand that comment. So far as I can tell you are imagining a problem that is not real. You can just use a function. Or if the issue is that `FieldByName(...)` is called inside a loop, call it outside the loop and store the returned field in a variable which you can use.

Comment: @Matej.
is this inline function
function quantity : Integer; inline;
begin
    result := ProductsForSale.fieldByName ("quantity"). asInteger ;
end;
equivalent in code with "ProductsForSale.fieldByName ("quantity"). asInteger " ?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan. I usually use long names in variables and fields to be understandable in terms of content. Thus, some complex operations have a long length and it becomes difficult to understand the rest of the code. Especially when there are several (but different) such operations within a logical section. If I could substitute these operations with aliases, a logical unit would be immediately understood.

Comment: In Delphi what you are describing is a function. I know you've got it into you head that a function is not what you need, but I'm sure you are wrong.

Comment: I have no doubt that a function can be used but something like: `#DEFINE quantity = ProductsForSale.fieldByName ("quantity").asInteger' would make it easier for me. What is your opinion about the online function?

Comment: It would not make it easier for you. You might think that, but you'd discover, as have all C and C++ programmers, that macros, in the long run, lead to more pain than benefit. Why do you think that one of the tenets of modern C++ is not to use macros? Inline function is probably pointless. Won't make any difference to performance. As I've already said, if you have performance issues then what you are proposing won't help. If you have performance issues, you should solve. Do you want to solve your performance issues?

Comment: Have you perhaps considered of dynamically creating [TIntegerField](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TIntegerField) and then setting its `FiledName` property to `'quantity'` and thus connecting it to specific field/column in your database?

Answer (score 1):

No, *Delphi* (and *Pascal*) knows

- neither **aliases** (using a different name for a type/variable/function still needs you to define it anew),
- nor **macros** (executing code in the compiler's context is very limited, mostly definings and conditions).

Even if, chances are you'd have to define it bound to a given context/scope: i.e. your favorite alias `TooMuchToType` might access three variables named `one`, `two` and `three`, but as per scope those variable's types can vary drastically. Its usage would be prone to obfuscated code and a lot of hassle the compiler has to go thru when trying to give you an error message he wants you to understand.

Why not doing exactly that at the end, but in the opposite way? First using a placeholder and when you're done you replace all of them with the actual code. Otherwise this is bascially what functions are there for, if you want it or not.

Comment: I thought of it as a simple text replacement before compiling. In this case there would be no problem with the type of variables. From what I understand, this possibility is not supported. But I think it would be very useful (and easy to add to the IDE)

Comment: It wouldn't be much use in the IDE, it would need to be a compiler level feature. And our experience from C and C++ is that pre-processor macros are an anti-feature. A large amount of the development of C++ is to provide features that make macros redundant.

Comment: Note that [FreePascal DOES have macros](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/current/prog/progse5.html)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Oh no. OH! NO!!! FreePascal can't be more [greek: Ἐπιμηθεύς ignored Προμηθεύς and married Πανδώρα](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandora).